# Querying JSON Object in Java

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson, jsonpath

Suppose my JSON is :

```
{
  "Name" : "Anmol Jain",
  "Address" : [
     {
       "type" : "home",
       "category" : "primary",
       "street" : "ABC"
     },
     {
       "type" : "home",
       "category" : "secondary",
       "street" : "XYZ"
     },
     {
       "type" : "work",
       "category" : "primary",
       "street" : "PQR"
     }
  ]
}
```

I am designing a specific syntax for my project so that I can query the JSON.
For Example :

```
Address(type = home; category = secondary).street
```

this should give me result as "XYZ".

The first approach that comes to my mind is to parse the above code syntax, and look for conditions like type and category (by string parsing).
then loop through Address array and try to match those conditions. But this will give higher time complexity in case of large JSONs.

Is there any library which does that. Or if anyone can suggest me better approach. The syntax for the condition is flexible and I can mould it accordingly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, use library "Josson & Jossons"

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
implementation 'com.octomix.josson:josson:1.3.22'

------------------------------------------------

Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
        "{" +
        "  \"Name\" : \"Anmol Jain\"," +
        "  \"Address\" : [" +
        "     {" +
        "       \"type\" : \"home\"," +
        "       \"category\" : \"primary\"," +
        "       \"street\" : \"ABC\"" +
        "     }," +
        "     {" +
        "       \"type\" : \"home\"," +
        "       \"category\" : \"secondary\"," +
        "       \"street\" : \"XYZ\"" +
        "     }," +
        "     {" +
        "       \"type\" : \"work\"," +
        "       \"category\" : \"primary\"," +
        "       \"street\" : \"PQR\"" +
        "     }" +
        "  ]" +
        "}");
String street = josson.getString("Address[type='home' & category='secondary'].street");
```

Comment: this is a great library.

Answer (score 1):

Besides @tgdavies mentioned, also have a look at https://github.com/eiiches/jackson-jq, it uses the same syntax of [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq), but in java implementation.